# Remove the default :size from form.text_field method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I see myself writing a lot of `:size => nil` for `f.text_field` as so:

```
<%= f.text_field :street_address, :size => nil %>
<%= f.text_field :post_code, :size => nil %>
<%= f.text_field :city, :size => nil %>
```

Which is just dumb. Without the `:size => nil` above, text_field renders an `<input>` with a `size="some number"` (usually `size="30"`) which I don't need or want there.

So, how can I implement DRY and make it so that `f.text_field` would not generate the `size=30` or `size="some number"` attribute by default? This way I can avoid always having to type `:size => nil`.

Comment: Overwrite `form` in ApplicationHelper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All default field options are stored in one hash. It defaults to the following:

```
# action_view/helpers/form_helper
DEFAULT_FIELD_OPTIONS = { "size" => 30 }
```

You can delete "size" from it in an initializer, for example.

```
ActionView::Helpers::InstanceTag::DEFAULT_FIELD_OPTIONS.delete("size")
```

Comment: Very nice! This works, is application wide and was easy to implement by simply adding the size deletion to `config/initializers/modify_form_defaults.rb`, which I created.

Answer (score 4):

Rails extends Object class with [`with_options` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-with_options). You can take advantage of it:

```
<%= form_for :foo do |f| %>
    <% f.with_options :size => nil do |f_nil| %>
        <%= f_nil.text_field :street_address %>
        <%= f_nil.text_field :post_code %>
        <%= f.text_field :city %> <!-- you can use old f here too! -->
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Gives:

```
<input id="foo_street_address" name="foo[street_address]" type="text" />
<input id="foo_post_code" name="foo[post_code]" type="text" />
<input id="foo_city" name="foo[city]" size="30" type="text" /> <!-- you can use old f here too! -->
```

Comment: Thanks! I like this method, too. The removal of `size` is clearly described in the view and not "hidden way in some initializer".

But with a form-heavy app (like what we're building here), this would not implement DRY 100%, so I liked Semyon's answer better :)

Answer (score 0):

Try encapsulating the text_field like so:

```
def no_size_text_area(form, method) form.text_area(method, {:size => nil}) end
```

put the function in your helper file.

and using no_size_text_area in its place like so:

```
no_size_text_area(f,:city)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Rails Team has since removed these defaults as of version `4.0.x`. There is no way to set global defaults anymore either. The only easy solution is to use CSS to set the dimensions.